# Where are the locations of the elevators or horizontal stabilizers in a Concorde?

Tags: flight-controls, flight-instruments, concorde, elevator

I don't find the horizontal stabilizers or the elevators of a Concorde at the tail section like other aircrafts. Are they fitted beside the ailerons in the wings?[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no "horizontal stabilizer" on the Concorde like other commercial aircraft, the wing performs that duty because it is a delta-wing. The elevators for the Concorde are combined with the ailerons into something called "elevons" which perform both functions (Think stereotype paper airplane).

Note: Elevators and Horizontal stabilizers are not the same thing. Most aircraft have their elevators located on their horizontal stabilizers, only a few have the whole stabilizer as an elevator.

Source [here](http://www.concordesst.com/wing.html)

Comment: Are both the elevons rised or lowered at the same time in a Concorde to make it descend or ascend?

Comment: @DwiparnaDatta: Yes. Google "elevons". They're used often on jet fighters that don't have separate elevators. Moving the stick up and down make the elevons move in the same direction (down and up) like an elevator. Moving the stick left and right make the elevons move in opposite directions like ailerons. In a turn where you're controlling both aileron and elevators the elevons move slightly up and slightly in opposite directions.